# Как добавить колонку на основании значений предыдущих записей в рамках окна?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть такая таблица, где `client_id` - ид клиента, `months` - месяцы, когда с клиентом был контракт.

Пока такой запрос:

```
select client_id, months, LAG(sas) OVER( PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY months) renew 
from (
    select client_id, months, months_between (
        LEAD (TO_DATE (T0_CHAR(TO_DATE (months, 'yyyymm'), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dd.mm.yyyy')) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY months),
        to_DATE (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE (months, 'yyyymm'), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'dd.mm.yvyy')) sas 
    from renew_clients)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, из таблицы, у клиента был договор с января 2018 г по апрель 2018 г. В конце апреля договор был закрыт. Потом, тот же клиент заключил контракт в ноябре 2018 г., то есть через 7 месяцев. В колонке `renew` признак повторного заключения контракта, если поле не равно 1, то считается что клиент  повторно заключил контракт.

Значение `renew` нашел как разницу между следующим и текущим значением поля `months`:

```
months_between(
    lead(to_date(to_char(to_date(months,'yyyymm'),'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')) 
        over (partition by client_id order by months), 
    to_date(to_char(to_date(months,'yyyymm'),'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy'))
```

Задача: если клиент повторно заключил контракт, то этот признак должен быть во всех последующих запписях данного клиента.

Пример желаемого результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу подсказать, намекнуть - какими методами, функциями можно реализовать эту задачу?

---

Тестовые данные:

```js
    Create table renew_clients(client_id number, months varchar2(20)); 
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201801');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201802');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201803');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201804');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201811');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201812');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201901');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201902');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201903');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(15154156, '201904');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(19542330, '201808');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(19542330, '201809');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(19542330, '201902');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(19542330, '201903');
    Insert into renew_clients(client_id,months) values(19542330, '201904');
```

Comment: А с чем возникли сложности, получить желаемый результат?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, забыл сообщить. Проблема в том, что я не знаю какими методами можно реализовать задачу

Comment: Извините, а где взять данные, которые у вас на картинке? Вручную набивать?

Comment: сорри, добавил код

Comment: Ещё уточнение, вы уверены, что результат на первой картинке вы получили именно той строчкой кода, которую опубликовали?

Comment: да, той строчкой, однако, забыл указать что к полученному значению я еще применил lag. Код запроса добавил.

Comment: *В конце апреля договор был закрыт.* Показанные исходные данные не содержат подобной информации. *Как видно, из таблицы, у клиента был договор с января 2018 г по апрель 2018 г.* А мне кажется, что это записи о двух разных договорах -  первый с января по февраль, второй с марта по апрель. Докажите, что это не так, причём а) однозначно б) только на основании показанных данных.

Comment: Если разница между месяцами больше 1 месяца, считается что договор был закрыт. То есть, если после апреля не следует май, значит в апреле договор закрыт.

Comment: @Akina, уместный вопрос, но сам бизнес-процесс предполагает невозможность заключения нового контракта, пока не пройдет 30 рабочих дней.

Comment: Т.е. можно сформулировать так: отсутствие записи хотя бы за один месяц означает завершение договора "до" и открытие договора "после", и наоборот - закрытие одного договора и открытие другого обязательно порождает пропущенный месяц в данных. Если так, то это обычный "gaps and islands", каждый договор есть остров дат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select d.*, max (renew) over (partition by client_id, grp) flag
from (
    select d.*,  
        sum (case when renew = 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
            over (partition by client_id order by months) grp 
    from ( 
        select d.*, 
            months_between (to_date (months,'yyyymm'), to_date (lag (months) 
                over (partition by client_id order by months), 'yyyymm')) renew  
        from renew_clients d) d) d
order by client_id, months
```

Результат:

```
 CLIENT_ID MONTHS      RENEW        GRP       FLAG
---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
  15154156 201801       null          1          1
  15154156 201802          1          1          1
  15154156 201803          1          1          1
  15154156 201804          1          1          1
  15154156 201811          7          2          7
  15154156 201812          1          2          7
  15154156 201901          1          2          7
  15154156 201902          1          2          7
  15154156 201903          1          2          7
  15154156 201904          1          2          7
  19542330 201808       null          1          1
  19542330 201809          1          1          1
  19542330 201902          5          2          5
  19542330 201903          1          2          5
  19542330 201904          1          2          5
```

Comment: Ваш вариант полностью удовлетворяет решению задачи, благодарю

Comment: Рад был помочь! Технически всё ок, но в бизнес логике так и не поял, какую роль могут играть эти 7 и 5. Это перерывы перед заключением нового контракта. Зачем  их в каждой записи выводить? Просто у меня был проект связаный с контрактами, которые постоянно, то обрывались, то возобнвлялись, не помню, чтобы я такое там делал.

Comment: грубо говоря, рядом с этими данными указывается некий финансовый показатель за этот месяц. Вся информация заносится в историю клиента, и менеджер в CRM уже по полю FLAG может определить, является ли данный клиент "вернувшимся", и если да, то через какое время .

Comment: Ааа, понял, чем быстрей вернётся, тем больше скидку получит.